# Angular ngClass is not updating my classes even though my condition change as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-class

I have something like this in a template I am creating

```
<div ui-view id="app" class="nng-3" ng-class="{ 'app-mobile': app.isMobile, 'app-navbar-fixed': app.layout.isNavbarFixed, 'app-sidebar-fixed': app.layout.isSidebarFixed, 'app-sidebar-closed': app.layout.isSidebarClosed, 'app-footer-fixed': app.layout.isFooterFixed }"></div>
```

The values `app.layout.isNavbarFixed`, etc are initialized with either zero or one, and for the first time the page loads the appropriate classes are inserted into my `div`. Any change after that though, by means of a button that sets those values, is not reflected on my `class` attributes by `ng-class`.

If I directly print those variables in my template, eg. `{{app.layout.isSidebarFixed}}` I can see them changing from `true` to `false` and vice versa, but `ng-class` will not update or remove any new classes.

I am not sure where to begin and look for the solution for this since with my limited knowledge I cant spot any obvious mistake immediately. Does anyone have any idea on what causes this issue?

Comment: You outputs `{{app.layout.isSidebarFixed}}` but in ng-class use `app.isSidebarFixed` without `layout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround of mine is to manipulate a model variable just for the ng-class toggling:

1) Whenever my list is empty, I update my model:

```
$scope.extract = function(removeItemId) {
    $scope.list= jQuery.grep($scope.list, function(item){return item.id != removeItemId});
    if (!$scope.list.length) {
        $scope.liststate = "empty";
    }
}
```

2) Whenever my list is not empty, I set another state

```
$scope.extract = function(item) {
    $scope.list.push(item);
    $scope.liststate = "notempty";
}
```

3) I use this additional model on my ng-class:

```
ng-class="{'bg-empty': liststate == 'empty', 'bg-notempty': liststate == 'notempty'}"
```

Update*: Also you can add any other states if needed and use at ng-class like:

```
ng-class="{'bg-empty': liststate == 'empty', 'bg-notempty': liststate == 'notempty', 'bg-additional-state', liststate == 'additional-state'}"
```

Because you know, an initially empty list state is not equal with a list which is emptied by command.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the ng-class implementation is not considering "0" to be "false" as you expect, because it's doing an strict comparision with ===.

Try expressing the conditions like this:

```
ng-class="{ 'app-mobile': app.isMobile == 0, 'app-navbar-fixed': app.layout.isNavbarFixed == 0, ...
```

Comment: In that case why is it working the first time I load the page though. Moreover "0" is certainly recognized as false. I did try the suggestion though but nothing came of it.

Comment: Then it seems a problem with scopes. Try printing the variables in your template but inside the ui-view, in the case you're not doing so, and test... It's hard to tell without seeing the context. Can you provide a Codepen or similar?

Comment: I generally do provide codepens because obviously for someone to identify an issue when he cant even see all of the app is quite hard. But in this case its a bit hard since I dont have a clean and easy to copy code. I will try and update the question if I manage to create one though. The variables still print as true or false inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your variant. Have everything working. Please, check if your button click event is on $scope and AngularJS knows, that values changed.

For example, if function triggered by native DOM Event (some jQuery table updated or something) than you should use $apply function, to reflect changes on scope. Something like this:

```
$scope.eventHandler = function(e) {
  $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.someProp = e.value;}
}
```

In the mean time, check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlexEmashev/byuLnr9L/)

**Update:**
Please check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byuLnr9L/26/) out. This works in AngularJS 1.4.8, but doesn't in other, that support jsfiddle. From what I know, it's not really a best idea to do an assignment inside of expression, the controller is meant for this thing.

Comment: $scope.$apply() triggers digest circle on $scope, and angular'll sync. all changes.

Comment: Since every time I press one of the buttons the variable values change, as it gets reflected on my template then I assumed until now that there is no tneed to initiate a digest myself. I actually do this to change the values:

`<span class="" ng-click="undefined ? app.layout.isNavbarFixed : app.layout.isNavbarFixed=!app.layout.isNavbarFixed" ng-model="app.layout.isNavbarFixed"><small></small><input type="checkbox" ng-model="app.layout.isNavbarFixed" style="display:none" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty"><span class="switch-text"> </span></span>`