# The Binding Only Updates After Clicking the Element, Though the String in the Controller Has Already Been Updated (Angular 1.5)

Tags: data-binding, reload, page-refresh, ng-class, angularjs-1.5

I have an `ng-class` attribute (that I didn't write on my own). It is bound to a string variable in the controller . It looks like: `<some-tag ng-class="'indicator_' + $ctrl.stringValue"></some-tag>`.

When the window first load - it contain the correct data, but after the string is updated in the controller - the value in the `class` attribute only updates after I'm clicking the element (the click will open a list, but I don't think it's relevant).

I've read that the first thing to check in these cases, is that the code is surrounded by a `$scope.$apply`. It is, cause when I try to add it - I get an error saying "$digest already in progress".
Looking for `$ctrl` and `ng-class` info, I read the [AngularJS component doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) and [this site](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass), that gave me some basic background about these subjects.

The thing is, I couldn't find any examples of `ng-class` with `$ctrl`. Maybe it's irrelevant, but maybe not :)

Example for an irrelevant question I found in the subject is: [Angular ngClass is not updating my classes even though my condition change as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35651732/angular-ngclass-is-not-updating-my-classes-even-though-my-condition-change-as-ex).
In general, most of the examples I found include curly brackets, which I don't think are relevant in this case, since I'm binding a string (maybe I'm mistaking about it :) ).

I suspect it probably didn't bind it correctly, I just don't know why.

---

**Edit:**

After continuing to search the subject, I'm no longer sure it's related to the `ng-class` (so I edited the title as well). It looks more like a refresh problem.

I'm puzzled as to why the page doesn't refresh, since everywhere I read - they say that the Angular should call the digest function on its own, and I should not interfere.

**Edit2:**

I'm working with `typeScript`, and the `stringValue` is updated via an event from a service. But the string does update - so I'm not sure it is a relevant information to understand the problem, but worth mentioning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!! :D

All I had to do, is to add `$timeout(0)` after updating the string in the controller!

The explanation: it was a digest problem, and the reason I couldn't use `$scope.$apply()`, is because I was trying to do it directly. I needed to do a *safe apply*, which means - first make sure there's no digest on that scope, and then run apply.

Turns out that an easy way to do it, is to use `$timeout(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a plunker with Angular 1.5.7 with a demo of what you described. There doesn't seem to be any problem, or anything special you should do. (I used a different alias for the controller, which is the best practice, but $ctrl works fine as well.)

https://plnkr.co/edit/wCpBQ5?p=preview

```js
const DemoComponent = {
  controller: DemoController,
  controllerAs: 'demoCtrl',
  template: `
    <h2 ng-class="'demo_' + demoCtrl.classSuffix">{{ demoCtrl.classSuffix }}</h2>
    <button ng-click="demoCtrl.changeClass()">Change Class</button>
    `
}

angular.module('myapp', [])
  .component('demo', DemoComponent);
```

It will be very helpful if you can reproduce the issue in plunker and post the link.
Otherwise, I hope you find the answer in this plunker.

Comment: Shmool, thanks for you answer, but in my case - the `stringValue` is not updated as a result of a user action - it updates as a result of something that happens in code.

Comment: I've also edited the question - I'm working with `typeScript`, is it's relevant..
I cannot reproduce the problem, since I'm working with some other services, and using one of them to raise an event.
**But the point is -** a service raise an event, the controller catches it and update the string (the string does update!). But after that - the `$ctrl.stringValue` bind in the HTML doesn't update until the page refreshes, and it doesn't refresh on its own.